# FabricJs, I want to fit the canvas to the window with fabric point

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I do zooming in/out for canvas with fabricjs, I store the zooming out coordinates with zooming scale and undo this while zooming out, and in the last zoom out i make new point like this to return to zoom 1

```
canvas.zoomToPoint(new fabric.Point(first_x_coordinate, first_y_coordinate), 1);
```

And it works fine but while moving the mouse while zooming it make some deviation from fit the window size and some while background appears in left or right of the canvas

Is there a solution for this ?